# Add Price to the Main Price with CheckBox Checked

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to build a cart function for the existing Food ordering system.

There, the user can view the product price in

```
<div class="product__price m-t-5">
  <span class="product__price product__price--large">$@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ProductPrice)</span>
</div>
```

section.

If the selected product is customizable, I show the extra items in the view with Checkbox.

So what I want to know is, if the customer selects any extra items, the extra item price should be added to the main price.

Also, if a customer is unchecked, then it should subtract from the main amount.

Want to know how to do this using Javascript?

This is the HTML code.

```
  <div class="col-md-7">
   <div class="product-details-box m-b-60">
     <h4 class="font--regular m-b-20">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ProductName)</h4>
     <div class="product__price m-t-5">
       <span class="product__price product__price--large">$@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ProductPrice)</span>
     </div>
     <div class="product-var p-tb-30">
       <div class="product-quantity product-var__item d-flex align-items-center">
         <span class="product-var__text">Quantity: </span>
         <form class="quantity-scale m-l-20">
           <div class="value-button" id="decrease" onclick="decreaseValue()">-</div>
           <input type="number" id="number" name="number" value="1" />
           <div class="value-button" id="increase" onclick="increaseValue()">+</div>
         </form>
       </div>
       <div>
         <h4 class="font--regular m-b-20">Add Some Extra</h4> 
         @if (Model.CustomizableFoods.Count!=0) 
         { 
         foreach (var item in Model.CustomizableFoods)
         { 
         <div class="row">
           <ul class="list">
             <li class="list__item">
               <label class="label--checkbox">
                 <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; @item.ExtraItem - @item.Extra_Item_Price </label>
             </li>
           </ul>
         </div>
            } 
        }
       </div>
       <div class="product-var__item">
         <input class="btn btn--long btn--radius-tiny btn--green btn--green-hover-black btn--uppercase btn--weight m-r-20" type="submit" value="Add to cart" />
         <a href="wishlist.html" class="btn btn--round btn--round-size-small btn--green btn--green-hover-black">
           <i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
         </a>
       </div>
       <div class="product-var__item">
         <span class="product-var__text">Guaranteed safe checkout </span>
       </div>
       <div class="product-var__item d-flex align-items-center">
         <span class="product-var__text">Share: </span>
         <ul class="product-social m-l-20">
           <li>
             <a href="#">
               <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
             </a>
           </li>
           <li>
             <a href="#">
               <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
             </a>
           </li>
           <li>
             <a href="#">
               <i class="fab fa-pinterest-p"></i>
             </a>
           </li>
         </ul>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

This is a sample of the view,

[image]

I did this,

In the view

```
 @if (Model.CustomizableFoods.Count!=0) 
 { 
    foreach (var item in Model.CustomizableFoods) 
     {  
     <div class="row">
        <ul class="list">
            <li class="list__item">
                <label class="label--checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" onclick="thisChecked()" value="@item.Extra_Item_Price"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; @item.ExtraItem - @item.Extra_Item_Price </label>
            </li>
        </ul>
      </div> 
    } 
 }
```

in the script

```
< script >
  function thisChecked() {

    var sList = "";
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
      sList += "(" + $(this).val() + "-" + (this.checked ? "checked" : "not checked") + ")";
    });

    alert(sList);

  } <
  /script>
```

as a result the alert shows

```
(100.00-checked)(450.00-not checked)
```

So any way of getting only the selected value to one variable and checked or not checked to another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use data-attribute which will have the original amount of the product and using that you can add or subtract extra items inside `thisChecked` function

Also, make sure the attribute value should be updated always when you call your `decreaseValue / increaseValue` functions .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
function thisChecked(el) {

  var closest_price_element = $(el).closest('.product-details-box').find('span.product__price');
  var amount = parseFloat(closest_price_element.data('original')) ?? 0; //getting attr value ..
  $('.product-var input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
    amount += parseFloat($(this).val()); //loop and addiing items amt
  });

  closest_price_element.text('$' + amount); //change value of price

}

//***the data-attr should be updated..always..not sure about decreaseValue / increaseValue fn there also you need to update the data attr value so that it always take original amount .!!
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-7">
  <div class="product-details-box m-b-60">
    <h4 class="font--regular m-b-20">PIZZA</h4>
    <div class="product__price m-t-5">
      <!--here added orginal price in data attr data-original= '@model.ProductPrice' -->
      <span class="product__price product__price--large" data-original='1200'>$1200</span>
    </div>
    <div class="product-var p-tb-30">
      <div class="product-quantity product-var__item d-flex align-items-center">
        <span class="product-var__text">Quantity: </span>
        <form class="quantity-scale m-l-20">
          <div class="value-button" id="decrease" onclick="decreaseValue()">-</div>
          <input type="number" id="number" name="number" value="1" />
          <div class="value-button" id="increase" onclick="increaseValue()">+</div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h4 class="font--regular m-b-20">Add Some Extra</h4>

        <div class="row">
          <ul class="list">
            <li class="list__item">
              <label class="label--checkbox">
              <!--pass current element reference-->
                 <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" onclick="thisChecked(this)" value="10"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Cheese - 10  </label>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <ul class="list">
            <li class="list__item">
              <label class="label--checkbox">
                 <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" onclick="thisChecked(this)" value="100"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; XYZ - 100 </label>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution of your question :

1. Add a 'data-price' attribute in your html code:

```
    <span class="product__price product__price--large" data-price="1800"
                >$@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ProductPrice)</span
              >
```

2. Update the html code to render list of extra items:

```
    @if (Model.CustomizableFoods.Count!=0) 
     { 
        foreach (var item in Model.CustomizableFoods) 
         {  
         <div class="row">
            <ul class="list extra_items">
                <li class="list__item">
                    <label class="label--checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox extra_item" value="@item.Extra_Item_Price"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; @item.ExtraItem - @item.Extra_Item_Price </label>
                </li>
            </ul>
          </div> 
        } 
     }
```

3. And finally update the javascript code :

```
    < script >
        // Array of selected items / Items to calculate the price
      let all_items = [];
    
    //   Function to update the price in the UI
      const updatePrice = (JQueryThis) => {
        // Traversing the current card to get price of the cuurent item (not extra_item)
        const priceTag = JQueryThis.parentsUntil(".product-details-box")
          .parent()
          .children("div.product__price")
          .children("span.product__price");
    
        //   Initial price
        let totalPrice = 0;
        for (let item of all_items) {
          if (item.selected) {
            totalPrice += item.price;
          }
        }
    
        priceTag.text(totalPrice);
      };
    
      // This code will run when a user selects or deselects an extra item.
      $(".extra_item").change(function () {
    
        // Traverse HTML Tag in which the total price is rendered
        // I have used traversal to find the price tag of corresponding food product 
        In case if there is more than one food products available.
        const priceTag = $(this)
          .parentsUntil(".product-details-box")
          .parent()
          .children("div.product__price")
          .children("span.product__price");
    
        /*   A JavaScript array of objects that contains details of an extra item. for ex. {
            name: <extra_item__name>,
            price: <extra_item__price>,
            selected: <whether the user selected the extra item or not. true if selected and false if not so.>,
        }
        */
        const extra_items = Array.from(
          $(this).parents(".extra_items").children() // This will return <li> tag
        ).map((item) => {
          let [name, price] = item.innerText.split("-"); // Split the text from '-'
          return {
            name,
            price: Number(price),
            selected: item.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]").checked,
          };
        });
    
        // Update 'all_items' array with the main price and extra items
        all_items = [
          {
            price: Number(priceTag.attr("data-price")),
            selected: true,
          },
          ...extra_items,
        ];
    
        // Update the price in UI
        updatePrice($(this));
      });
    </script>
```

**Warning : Make sure to update the price in backend for security reasons.**